# type erasure без type_info

Tags: c++

Как реализовать type erasure без type_info?

Comment: `dynamic_cast`. Добавьте в вопрос больше деталей, тогда можно будет сказать точнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type erasure можно реализовать различными способами. Одним из самых распространенных способов является хранение указателей на статические функции, которые уже знают тип объекта. Другой способ - хринить некоторый числовой идентификатор типа и в зависимости от его значения совершать требуемые действия.

Пример первого подхода на шаблонах (лямбды преобразуются в указатели на функции): допустим, мы хотим хранить любой объект, имеющий функцию-член `int call(int)` и конструктор копирования, с возможностью вызова call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class call_wrapper{
    using deleter_fn_t = void  (*) (void*);
    using copy_fn_t =    void* (*) (void*);
    using call_fn_t =    int   (*) (void*, int);

  void* m_data;
  deleter_fn_t m_deleter_fn;
  copy_fn_t m_copy_fn;
  call_fn_t m_call_fn;

  public:
  call_wrapper()
    : m_data       { nullptr                                }
    , m_deleter_fn { [](void*){}                            } 
    , m_copy_fn    { [](void*)->void* { return nullptr;}    }
    , m_call_fn    { [](void*, int)->int { assert(false); } }
    { }
  template<class T>
  call_wrapper(const T& value)
    : m_data       { new T(value)                                                          }
    , m_deleter_fn { [](void* data) { delete static_cast<T*>(data); }                      }
    , m_copy_fn    { [](void* data)->void* { return new T(*static_cast<T*>(data)); }       }
    , m_call_fn    { [](void* data, int v)->int { return static_cast<T*>(data)->call(v); } }
  { }

  call_wrapper(const call_wrapper& lha)
    : m_data       { lha.m_copy_fn(lha.m_data) }
    , m_deleter_fn { lha.m_deleter_fn          }
    , m_copy_fn    { lha.m_copy_fn             }
    , m_call_fn    { lha.m_call_fn             }
  { }

  int call(int v) { return m_call_fn(m_data, v);}

  ~call_wrapper(){
     m_deleter_fn (m_data); 
  }
};

struct test1{
    int v;
    int call(int in) {return in + v;}

    test1(int v_): v{v_} {}
    test1(const test1& lha): v{lha.v + 10} {}
};

struct test2{
    int call(int) {return 42;}
};

int main()
{
  test1 t1 {10}; 
  test2 t2 {};

  call_wrapper c1{t1}; // Тут происходит копирование test1
  std::cout << "test 1 call: " << c1.call(0) << std::endl; // 20

  call_wrapper c11{c1}; // Тут происходит еще одно копирование test1
  std::cout << "test 1 copy call: " << c11.call(0) << std::endl; // 30
  std::cout << "test 1 original call: " << c1.call(0) << std::endl; // 20

  call_wrapper c2 {t2};
  std::cout << "test 2 call: " << c2.call(0) << std::endl; // 42
}
```